# Need clarification on definition of cantor distribution

Tags: probability, cantor-set

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution it says it's a probability distribution with CDF the cantor function $C(x)$. I'm a bit confused on what the probability distribution actually is. Is the sample space here defined to be $[0,1]$, and the probability $P$ on $[0,1]$ is defined like the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ but with $P([a,b])=C(b)-C(a)$, instead of $P([a,b])=b-a$ like with the usual Lebesgue measure? So $P$ is $1$ on the cantor set, and is $0$ on it's complement?

Comment: It is not clear what you think $P$ is here:  the Cantor distribution does not have a probability mass function or a probability density on the Cantor set (it does on the complement but it is $0$ there).   It is true that $\mathbb P(X \in [a,b]) =C(b)-C(a)$ for $0\le a\le b\le 1$, but that is insufficient for what you say next: "$P$ is $1$ on the Cantor set" is incorrect

Comment: What I meant is how to define $P(M)$ for any measurable set $M$. Is it defined like the usual Lebesgue measure, but with the "length" of $[a,b]$ equal to $C(b)-C(a)$ instead of $b-a$? If it's done like this, then $P(cantor set)=1$.

Comment: If $K$ is the Cantor set, then $P(M)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\{C(m):m \in M \cap K\}$.  An illustration of the difficulty with your length approach is that it would not allow you to find that $P(K)=1$ as $K$ is the uncountable union of intervals of length $0$ and measure $0$.